# Cannot deserialize instance Kafka Streams

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

What am I doing wrong, My below kafka stream program giving issue while streaming the data, "Cannot deserialize instance of com.kafka.productiontest.models.TimeOff out of START_ARRAY token ".

I have a topic timeOffs2 which contain time offs information with key timeOffID and value is of type object which contain employeeId. I just want to group all time offs for employee key and write to the store.

For store key will be employeeId and value will be list of timeoffs.

Program properties and streaming logic:

```
public Properties getKafkaProperties() throws UnknownHostException {

    InetAddress myHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

    Properties kafkaStreamProperties = new Properties();
    kafkaStreamProperties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    kafkaStreamProperties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
    kafkaStreamProperties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, TimeOffSerde.class);
    kafkaStreamProperties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    kafkaStreamProperties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "com.kafka.productiontest.models.TimeOffSerializer");
    kafkaStreamProperties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, application_id );
    kafkaStreamProperties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_SERVER_CONFIG, myHost.getHostName() + ":" + port);
    return kafkaStreamProperties;
}



  String topic = "timeOffs2";
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

KStream<String, TimeOff> source = builder.stream(topic);

KTable<String, ArrayList<TimeOff>> newStore = source.groupBy((k, v) -> v.getEmployeeId())
    .aggregate(ArrayList::new,
        (key, value, aggregate) -> {
          aggregate.add(value);
          return aggregate;
        }, Materialized.as("NewStore").withValueSerde(TimeOffListSerde(TimeOffSerde)));

final Topology topology = builder.build();
final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, getKafkaProperties());
```

TimeOffSerializer.java

```
ackage com.kafka.productiontest.models;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;

import java.util.Map;

public class TimeOffSerializer implements Serializer  {

  @Override
  public void configure(Map configs, boolean isKey) {

  }

  @Override
  public byte[] serialize(String topic, Object data) {
    byte[] retVal = null;
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
      retVal = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data).getBytes();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return retVal;
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
  }
}
```

TimeOffDeserializer.java

```
package com.kafka.productiontest.models;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer ;

import java.util.Map;

public class TimeOffDeserializer implements Deserializer {

  @Override
  public void configure(Map configs, boolean isKey) {

  }
  @Override
  public TimeOff deserialize(String arg0, byte[] arg1) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TimeOff timeOff = null;
    try {
      timeOff = mapper.readValue(arg1, TimeOff.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return timeOff;
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {

  }

}
```

TimeOffSerde.java

```
package com.kafka.productiontest.models;

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;

import java.util.Map;

public class TimeOffSerde implements Serde<Object> {

  private final Serde inner;

  public TimeOffSerde(){
    inner = Serdes.serdeFrom(new TimeOffSerializer(), new TimeOffDeserializer());
  }
  @Override
  public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
    inner.serializer().configure(configs, isKey);
    inner.deserializer().configure(configs, isKey);
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    inner.serializer().close();
    inner.deserializer().close();
  }

  @Override
  public Serializer<Object> serializer() {
    return inner.serializer();
  }

  @Override
  public Deserializer<Object> deserializer() {
    return inner.deserializer();
  }
}
```

TimeOffListSerializer.java

```
package com.kafka.productiontest.models;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class TimeOffListSerializer implements Serializer<ArrayList<TimeOff>> {

  private Serializer<TimeOff> inner;

  public TimeOffListSerializer(Serializer<TimeOff> inner) {
    this.inner = inner;
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {

  }

  @Override
  public byte[] serialize(String topic, ArrayList<TimeOff> data) {
    final int size = data.size();
    final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
    final Iterator<TimeOff> iterator = data.iterator();
    try {
      dos.writeInt(size);
      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        final byte[] bytes = inner.serialize(topic, iterator.next());
        dos.writeInt(bytes.length);
        dos.write(bytes);
      }

    }catch (Exception ex) {

    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
      inner.close();
  }
}
```

TimeOffListDeserializer.java

```
package com.kafka.productiontest.models;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class TimeOffListDeserializer  implements Deserializer<ArrayList<TimeOff>> {

  private final Deserializer<TimeOff> valueDeserializer;

  public TimeOffListDeserializer(final Deserializer<TimeOff> valueDeserializer) {
    this.valueDeserializer = valueDeserializer;
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {

  }

  @Override
  public ArrayList<TimeOff> deserialize(String topic, byte[] data)  {
    if (data == null || data.length == 0) {
      return null;
    }

    final ArrayList<TimeOff> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    final DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));

    try {
      final int records = dataInputStream.readInt();
      for (int i = 0; i < records; i++) {
        final byte[] valueBytes = new byte[dataInputStream.readInt()];
        dataInputStream.read(valueBytes);
        arrayList.add(valueDeserializer.deserialize(topic, valueBytes));
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Unable to deserialize ArrayList", e);
    }
    return arrayList;
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {

  }
}
```

TimeOffListSerde.java

```
package com.kafka.productiontest.models;

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class TimeOffListSerde implements Serde<ArrayList<TimeOff>> {
  private Serde<ArrayList<TimeOff>> inner;

  public TimeOffListSerde() {
  }

  public TimeOffListSerde(Serde<TimeOff> serde){
    inner = Serdes.serdeFrom(new TimeOffListSerializer(serde.serializer()), new TimeOffListDeserializer(serde.deserializer()));
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
    inner.serializer().configure(configs, isKey);
    inner.deserializer().configure(configs, isKey);
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    inner.serializer().close();
    inner.deserializer().close();
  }

  @Override
  public Serializer<ArrayList<TimeOff>> serializer() {
    return inner.serializer();
  }

  @Override
  public Deserializer<ArrayList<TimeOff>> deserializer() {
    return inner.deserializer();
  }
}
```

I think issue is in this part with withValueSerde. I can not compile with this code. But if I remove withValueSerde, it is giving me this issue "Can not deserialize TimeOff object". Can you please help and guide what I am doing wrong.

```
KTable<String, ArrayList<TimeOff>> newStore = source.groupBy((k, v) -> v.getEmployeeId())
    .aggregate(ArrayList::new,
        (key, value, aggregate) -> {
          aggregate.add(value);
          return aggregate;
        }, Materialized.as("NewStore").withValueSerde(TimeOffListSerde(TimeOffSerde)));
```

Comment: If you're doing `writeValueAsString` anyway, why not just use the StringSerializer and map your objects to strings? Then, why are you using DataOutputStream rather than Jackson to parse the data back to an object? Hint: write unit tests for your serializers

Comment: Will do write test cases, but what is wrong with this approach. If I am going with this code (even it is very dirty written), what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Somewhere in the serialization pipeline, it is trying to deserialize your list as a single TimeOff object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code I can see several issues:

1. TimeOffSerde - It should implement `Serde<TimeOff>` not `Serde<Object>`
2. You don't pass types for Key and Value in `Materialized`, so it assume it is `Object`

So your streaming part should be something like:

```
KTable<String, ArrayList<TimeOff>> newStore = source.groupBy((k, v) -> v.getEmployeeId())
        .aggregate(ArrayList::new,
                (key, value, aggregate) -> {
                    aggregate.add(value);
                    return aggregate;
                }, Materialized.<String, ArrayList<TimeOff>, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("NewStore").withValueSerde(new TimeOffListSerde(new TimeOffSerde())));
```

**NOTICE**: Rember to clear state store directory after modification.

Comment: Wow. Genius. one more question. is it necessary to write value to store as byte[] . If yes is there any specific reason and how I convert byte[] back to list<Timeoff> objects.

Comment: Any help. I am new to kafka streams. that's why asking too many questions. Please answer only this question how to convert byte[] back to list of timeoff objects.

Comment: @Parkashkumar, to convert byte[] back to POJO (list of timeoffs) you need to use your `Deserializer` - `TimeOffListDeserializer`.

Comment: @Parkashkumar, Kafka treats messages - key, values - as array of bytes, that the reason why state store is byte[]

Comment: If I use KTable (talking about source table) instead of KStreams, will it still be the same code still? Because As I changed KStream to KTable, it started giving issues. It was stating issue with aggegates.

Comment: @Parkashkumar, please ask new question or add sample code with exception